# sudo no password breaks other sudo -u uses

Tags: linux

I have a virtual machine running ubuntu server (latest LTS forget the actual version number). I have setup sudo not to ask for a password but when I did that I could no longer run psql as postgres user using sudo -u unless i was root.

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

I now get a password prompt and then this message after i enter my password ...

```
Sorry, user _____ is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/psql' as postgres on ...
```

sudoers file

```
root ALL=(ALL) ALL
%admin ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Comment: Any idea why the down vote? Not bothered but would help to know so that in the future my questions can better.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but you should probably post these types of questions to either http://superuser.com or http://askubuntu.com.

Comment: As @mevatron stated, your question is off topic (I didn't downvote it btw). Read the faq to know what kind of questions belong on SO

Comment: Thanks. Do i as the OP have a way to move the question or should i not ever bother since i have the answer i needed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming your user is in the `admin` group, modify the second line to

```
%admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

to allow passwordless sudo to every user, not only root. Your current config allows

- root to run anything as anyone
- users from the `admin` group to run anything as root without password

as there is no runas-specification `(ALL)` making it possible to run as anyone.